# Java Mail API - Mail Doesn't Send

Tags: java, email, servlets, jakarta-mail

I have a Java web project. I am trying to add a contact us part to my web project. There no anything that Netbeans warn me but when I fill the textboxes and click button mail doesn't sent.

Here is my code of servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MailDispatcherServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MailDispatcherServlet"})
public class MailDispatcherServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    @EJB
    private MailSenderBean mailSender;
    

    
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        
        String toEmail = request.getParameter("email");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String message = request.getParameter("message");
        
        String fromEmail = "gorkemsoftware@gmail.com"; 
        String usurname = "gorkemsoftware"; 
        String password = "mypasword"; 
        
        
        
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            
            mailSender.sendEmail(fromEmail, usurname, password, toEmail, subject, message);
            
            
            
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>MAIL STATUS</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>MAIL STATUS !!!</h1>");
            out.println("<b>MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY  </b><br>"); 
            out.println("Click <a href='frmMail.jsp'>here</a> to go back!!!");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
```

And here is my code of Bean:

```
@Stateless
public class MailSenderBean {
    
    public void sendEmail(String fromEmail, String username, String password,
            String toEmail, String subject, String message){
        
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "stmp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
           
            
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            mailSession.setDebug(true);
            
            Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
            mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
            
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
            
            transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailSenderBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this project? The mail address and password is also correct. And I changed security setting on gmail.

and here is the output when I click send button:

> MAIL STATUS !!!
>
> MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY
> Click here to go back!!!

Comment: Is there any exception in logs?

Comment: I'd love to code better than now to understand what do you mean... :)

Comment: I meant there must have been some error log printed to the console of netbeans, do you see any error there when you click send button?

Comment: When I click send button the output is: AIL STATUS !!!

MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY Click here to go back!!!   -- So it doesn't give me any error. When run the file itself /Users/GorkemKiziltas/NetBeansProjects/SEN2001_Project_02/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1160: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/GorkemKiziltas/NetBeansProjects/SEN2001_Project_02/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1170: 
org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.DebuggerStartException: Connection refused (Connection refused) This is the output on netbeans output panel

Answer (score 0):

I think we have pb when send mail by SSL (port 465):
I prefer some changes in your code like this :

```
public void sendEmail(String fromEmail, String username, String password,
        String toEmail, String subject, String message){
    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "stmp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); // added
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(username, password); // changed
        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, auth); // changed
        mailSession.setDebug(true);

        Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
        mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);

        InternetAddress[] smtpAddress = { new InternetAddress("stmp.gmail.com") }; // changed
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport(smtpAddress[0]); // changed
        transport.connect();// changed

        transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close(); // added
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MailSenderBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The class SMTPAuthenticator :

```
private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    SMTPAuthenticator(String user, String pass) {
        username = user;
        password = pass;
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your respond. Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(username, password); this line give me an error which I don't understand.

Comment: and also on this line: Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport(smtpAddress); I think I am missing a point that I cannot see...

Comment: Sorry man, i forgot the SMTPAuthenticator class. And the getTransport method need InternetAddress param, not array InternetAddress.